# Google Spreadsheet Pushing to Array

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Google sheets script which I hear is complete Javascript so I'm told. I'm just trying to create a list of quests relevant to an item in an online game by parsing the HTML in the spreadsheet.

Example: http://everquest.allakhazam.com/db/item.html?item=14295

Ideally in this case it should bring across the 4 quest names, their location and the quest ID (which can be found within the URL in the source code). But I'm just trying to pull the quest ID at the moment as can be found below.

```
function myFunction(itemid) {

  var regexp = /quest.html\?quest\=(.*)"/;
  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://everquest.allakhazam.com/db/item.html?item=' + itemid).getContentText();
  var matches = [];
  var number = page.match(/<li><a href="\/db\/quest.html\?quest\=(.*)"/); 

 for (var i in number) {
   matches.push(number[i]);
 }

 return matches;
}
```

But the script just seems to hang on 'Loading..' and doesn't do anything. If I add 'return number just after the page.match it returns the first quest ID fine.. so it seems it may be related with pushing to the array which is causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to parse *HTML* as text. You can use a formula with `importxml` function to get your data using *XPath*:

```
=importxml("http://everquest.allakhazam.com/db/item.html?item=14295";"//div[@id='quest']//b|//div[@id='quest']/ul/li/a|//div[@id='quest']/ul/li/a/@href")
```